# Creating a dynamic pivot with the headers as the first row

Tags: t-sql, pivot, union, pivot-table

I have created a procedure that makes a dynamic pivot so that I can sum up the hours worked on a project. On this pivot I would like to insert a row at the top with the column headers in.

This is how the tables look like

```
headers --> |  Name  |  Hours  |  Project  |
            |  Bill  |    30   |   proj1   |
            |  Steve |    34   |   proj1   |
            |  Bill  |    42   |   proj2   |
```

This is how the pivot looks like

```
headers --> |  Name  |  proj1  |  proj2  |
            |  Bill  |    30   |    42   |
            |  Steve |    34   |         |
```

This is how I would like to have it

```
headers --> | column1 | column2 | column3 |
            |  Name   |  proj1  |  proj2  |
            |  Bill   |    30   |    42   |
            |  Steve  |    34   |         |
```

Is there a way to do that by creating a temp table or something? 
And yes I need the headers as a row and not just column headers.

Comment: Name,proj1,proj2,..projn are themselves column-header not a row with desired data. Can you please tell us more about exactly what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I need to this I union a select that contains text with the query that needs the header rows.  To get them to the top you need to order by something that puts them at the top.  If you don't have anything add a fake field.

```
select 0 'orderby', col1, col2, col3 
from mytable
union
select -1, 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'
order by orderby
```